# Error TS2430: Interface 'RcFile' incorrectly extends interface 'File' in antd

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

```
C:\Users\SCC\Desktop\xxx\web-shop\node_modules\antd\lib\upload\interface.d.ts
(6,18): error TS2430: Interface 'RcFile' incorrectly extends interface 
'File'.
  Types of property 'lastModifiedDate' are incompatible.
  Type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
```

I pulled it down from git at home, and then ran, and I made a mistake.I don't know what the problem is,Can anyone help me？Thanks，The following is mine package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"antd": "^3.7.3",
"less": "^3.8.0",
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts-ts": "2.16.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/history": "^4.7.0",
"@types/jest": "^23.3.0",
"@types/react": "^16.4.7",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"less-loader": "^4.1.0",
"react-app-rewire-less": "^2.1.2",
"react-app-rewired": "^1.5.2",
"ts-import-plugin": "^1.5.4",
"typescript": "^2.9.2"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The antd library recently made a breaking change to its typings, and your version constraint auto updates to the latest version in the same major version, introducing the error. If you fix the antd version (remove the "^") and run `npm install` again you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, this method is not allowed.

Answer (score -2):

open `C:\Users\SCC\Desktop\xxx\web-shop\node_modules\antd\lib\upload\interface.d.ts`, then delete the **?** behind `lastModifiedDate`.